# SDK Version in eclipse is differ form what I installed

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i have recently installed eclipse Version: 4.2.1 with android SDK r21.
but when i want to start a new project with some of templates i get messages like this one:
"Navigation Type "Fixed Tabs + Swipe" requires a minimum SDK version of at least 11, and the current min version is 8"

since i have installed r21 from android does anyone know what eclipse is looking for???

Answer (score 6):

It's not about the SDK you installed but the minSDK that you set for your project. See screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new project it asks for the "minimum SDK_version" aswell. and its set to "8" by default.  so if you want to use newer techniques you have to change the minimum-sdk to a higher value.
 does that help, or do i need to be more precise? :)

Comment: the downside is, that older devices might get problems if your minimum-sdk is too high!